# Which is the real memory usage?

Tags: ubuntu, memory

Please, take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

You can see a discrepancy between memory usage value given at login (`Memory usage: 35%`) and the output from `free -h` (1.6 / 2.0 = 0.8 which is 80%).

Which one is the real one?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

buffers and cached values are interpreted as used by the os but they get freed if needed by applications.

So, used memory is `used - (buffers + cached)`.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/223759/how-to-read-correctly-output-of-free-m-command